# Ver stream en Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-imageview, bitmap

Estoy tratando de decodificar un stream a bitmap para poder pasarlo por un imageview y así reproducir un stream.

## Alternativa 1:

Me he basado en [esta pregunta de StackOverflow: How to load an ImageView by URL in Android? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)
 cogiendo lo que me ha parecido que necesitaba, pero cuando ejecuto la App llamando a `Funcion()` no consigo mostrar imagen.

¿Que estoy haciendo mal? He cogido las funciones equivalentes de `java` para `xamarin`, los objetos y demás coinciden entonces, no entiendo si es que está mal mi código o el stream o...

En mi caso he tratado de usar varias retransmisiones sacadas de distintos lugares. Youtube, twitch, alguna televisión que emite en directo o una ip local donde por http veo stream.

```
private void Funcion()
{
   ImageView image = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.vView);
   Bitmap stream = Task.Run(() => doInBackground()).Result;
   image.SetImageBitmap(stream);

}

protected Bitmap doInBackground()
{
    Bitmap stream;
    stream = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(new Java.Net.URL("URL").OpenStream());

    return stream;
}
```

> Esta es la vista que uso

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/vView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

> El `OnCreate()` solo tiene lo básico:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

    Funcion();

}
```

El código no tiene más.

## Alternativa 2

> Usar `VideoView`:

```
VideoView video = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.vView);


video.SetVideoURI(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("http://ip:puerto/"));
video.RequestFocus();
video.Prepared += delegate
{
   video.Start();
};
```

Esta opción es la que más sencilla me parece, pero cuando inicio me sale un dialogo en el que me dice: ** No se puede reproducir el vídeo.** y pues hasta ahí llego.

## Http

> Si  entro desde el navegador con http://ip:puerto/ y inspecciono el elemento lo que veo es esto:

```
<Body>
    <img style="-webkit-user-select: none;" src="http://ip:puerto/">
</Body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He conseguido una solución para esto, como el *stream* se puede ver desde cualquier navegador he optado por usar `WebView` para poder visualizar el "stream" que en realidad, parece ser una secuencia de imágenes y denegar el zoom y movimientos del `webview` para que así parezca un vídeo.

## Código C#:

```
var wPlayer = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
//Zoom Out para ajustar contenido a pantalla por width
wPlayer.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true; 
wPlayer.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;

wPlayer.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

wPlayer.LoadUrl("http://ip:port/?params");
```

## Axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<android.webkit.WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
/>


</RelativeLayout>
```